# Can't get left aligned triangle to be right aligned triangle

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i'm trying to make a right aligned triangle. I am able to make a left aligned triangle easily, but can't get the number of spaces to decrease with each additional row.

output should be:

```
       #
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
```

```js
let levels = 8;
let hash = '';

for (let i = 1; i <= levels; i++) {
    hash += '#';
    console.log(hash)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reusing the same string, consider generating each row with [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) and [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```js
function rightAlignedTriangle (levels) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= levels; i++) {
    const row = '#'.repeat(i).padStart(levels)
    console.log(row)
  }
}

rightAlignedTriangle(5)
```

To implement this using a nested loop instead of string methods, you can manually implement the above two methods as an inner loop on a variable string declared in the outer loop:

```js
function rightAlignedTriangle (levels) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= levels; i++) {
    let row = ''

    for (let j = 0; j < levels; j++) {
      if (j < i) { row += '#' } // repeat(i)
      else { row = ' ' + row } // padStart(levels)
    }

    console.log(row)
  }
}

rightAlignedTriangle(5)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! How this could be done with a nested loop though. That was the approach I was working on and have seen other languages use nested loops???

Comment: @TylerMorales if that was the approach you were working on then that was the approach you should have shared. You mentioned nothing about nested loops. But to answer your question without giving it away, consider how `repeat()` and `padStart()` modify the input string, and you'll have your implementation for your inner loop.